# Issue with multilevel inheritance

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, virtual

I have multilevel inheritance of 3 classes

```
class Product1
{
    public virtual void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Product1.show");
    }
}
class Product2 : Product1
{
    public override void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Product2.show");
    }
}
class Product3 : Product2
{
    public new void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Product3.show");
    }
}
```

At the time of object creation, I'm assigning object of Product3 to Product1.

```
class Products
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Product1 product1 = new Product1();
            Product3 product3 = new Product3();

            product1 = product3;

            product3.Show();
            product1.Show();
        }
    }
```

And called Show method. I thought in both the cases the answer would be Product3.show but not sure how Product2.show is being called.

[Console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHhDw.png)

Any help on the explanation would be appreciated :)

Comment: Note that instead of a screenshot, just "Output: " and then the output would be clearer.

Comment: If you already know the difference between `new` and `override` (because you use both), maybe you are confused that the `Prduct3.Show` is not called even if you assign an instance of `Prduct3`. The reason is that you assign it to a vaiable of type `Product1` and not `Product3`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I's expecting `Product3` twice! As I've assigned object of `Product3` to `Product1`. But as you clarified that it's not possible?! I'm still confused, why in the world `Product2`.Show came in the picture

Comment: @kardinal: What is expecting `Product3` twice and what is not possible? Sorry but your comment confuses me. Of course it's possible to get _"Show Product3"_ twice. You just need to replace the `new` keyword with `override`. The keyword `new` creates a new method which has nothing to do with the inherited method `Show`(just the name).

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I was expecting `Product3` twice as I assigned `Product3` to `Product1`. But as you said this assignment is not possible because 'Product1' is of different type. And I still don't know why `Product2` came into the picture

Comment: @kardinal: Of course the assignment is possible and in fact it works. You just dont get the expected output `"Product3.show"` if you assign the `Product3` to a `"Product1` variable. Therefore you have to assin it to a `Product3` variable or (normally the correct way) `override` the method instead of using `new`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, ok! but why `product1.Show()` prints Product2.show after `product1 = product3` ? :(

Comment: @kardinal: because you override `Show` in `Product2` and actually this is a `Product3` instance that inherits from `Product2`. Inheritance works even if you "hide" an instance in a parent type(class or interface).

Answer (score 1):

Your `Product3.Show` method is effectively an *entirely different method* as far as the compiler is concerned from `Product1.Show` which is overridden by `Product2.Show`. By using the `new` modifier you've explicitly isolated it from the existing `Show` method. The C# compiler (and CLR) are working exactly as I'd expect them to.

Basically if you *want* `Product3.Show` to be called even via a reference with a compile-time type of `Product1` or `Product2`, you should use `override` instead of `new`.

Comment: I'm still confused, why in the world `Product2.Show` came into the picture. :(

Comment: @kardinal: because you use `new` instead of `override` in `Product3`. Period.
You assign that `Product3` to a `Product1` variable, so the compiler loses the information that this `Product1` has a new implementation of `Show`(defined in `Product3)` and uses the normal inheritance to `Product2`. You would have to cast it to `Product3` before you call `Show` to be able to see the `"Product3.show"`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, could you please elaborate how in this case `new` is working? It should have only worked for `Product3`, where it used. Why it is working for `Product1` ? Just because of this - `product1 = product3`

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I did not read your edited version. Make sense now. Thanks Man